# Angular 5 ng-model template parsing issue

Tags: angular-ngmodel, angular5

I am using angular 5 and trying to use `[(ngModel)]="user.fname"` like that. I have also imported FormsModule in app.module.ts. But still I am having a template parsing issue.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

add formdodule to the app.module and imports.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';     
imports: [  FormsModule]
```